# Javascript get special cell value from all tr and display to json

Tags: javascript, json

I have long table to parse.But ı don't need them all.I have to need only [1],[2],[4],[5],[6],[9] cell values for each tr.

[image: DA.png]

I can get specific cell of the row with using code bellow.

```
document.getElementById("table-body-positions").rows[0].cells[5].innerText
```

But how can i do this for all tr.And how can i parse to json ?

[image: cells.png]

Comment: Please provide the HTML for that table (so we can more easily see your structure). Also, please add exactly the output you want (an example, not a description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the rows by checking if a row exists and then map the wanted cells.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table-body-positions"),
    cells = [0, 1, 4],
    row = 0,
    result = [];

while (table.rows[row]) {
    result.push({ ['order' + (row + 1)]: cells.map(cell => table.rows[row].cells[cell].innerText) });
    row++;
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<table id="table-body-positions">
    <tr><td>00</td><td>01</td><td>02</td><td>03</td><td>04</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td></tr>
    <tr><td>30</td><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td><td>34</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: TypeError: table.rows[row].cells[(cell - 1)] is undefined

Comment: it depends on your table ... which is unknown.

Comment: Okay i change table name and its work.And idea for export json ? I use something " var dozer = JSON.stringify(result); console.log(dozer)" It works but it's doesn't have to id like 1,2,3...

Comment: what does not work with `stringify? which result do you expect?

Comment: It's work.I asked how can i set id for each of them for retrieve later.

Comment: where do you get the `id` from?

Comment: How can i assign a number like "order1,[cell values],order2,[cell values],......"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186658/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-dorbagna).